# Google Analytics Custom Dimension Not Tracking Accurately

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, custom-dimensions

I have two custom dimensions set at the session-scope level within GA to capture an article's content category and subcategory in the blog of the site. GA populates these values about 60% of the time, with the rest not being set, and of the 60% that are populated, they're not always the proper category/subcategory for that blog post, but rather a different one.

You'll notice in the screenshot that the custom dimensions are being pushed, but the first GTM tracker (gtm2) is showing them as undefined, while the second tracker (gtm7) populates them from the datalayer.

[Console Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nfQdJ.jpg)

I'm using GTM to push the custom dimensions into the datalayer with the Google Analytics Settings variable. [Tag Manager Implementation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S0Wsq.png)

Have any suggestions on why the dimensions aren't populating properly within Google Analytics at the pageview level?

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that at the time of loading the GTM (`gtm.js`) the value of those variables is not yet available, while at load (`gtm.load`) it is.